# DJI Mavic Air 2 Camera can't set mode?

Tags: dji-sdk

I'm trying to see why our DJI-enabled app isn't working correctly with the Mavic Air 2 on iOS or Android. Here I'm debugging with iOS but I've seen the same failures when briefly testing on our Android app.

When calling `setMode:completion:` on the single camera belonging to the Mavic Air 2, I consistently get "Current product does not support this feature.(code:-1013)"

`isMediaDownloadModeSupported` returns true for the camera, and yet I can't set the camera mode to media download mode at all (or any other mode).

I've found that `setFlatMode:completion:` seems to work ok to set photo and video modes as a sort of alternative, however this is only for photo/video modes, and won't help me with downloading media from the SD card. (right?)

Any help out there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my DJI Developer Support ticket for the same issue:

> For the Mavic Air 2 drone, should use the [setFlatMode](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/android-api/Components/Camera/DJICamera.html#djicamera_setflatmode_inline) to switch the photo, video mode, and use the [enterPlayback](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/android-api/Components/Camera/DJICamera.html#djicamera_enterplayback_inline), [exitPlayback](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/android-api/Components/Camera/DJICamera.html#djicamera_exitplayback_inline) to enter/ exit the download mode.

Comment: Can you add a link to the ticket?